# Bind a Datagrid to a Linq query in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I've been working in client-service applications all my life so now that I can do "wild things" like having the DAO in the client I think things can be better done 8-)

When I loaded a GridView in a client-server application I used to have a pagination...

If I make the call to the database from the client... may I bind the GridView to a linq query directly or should I call to a "ToList" or something like that before? I think GridView could make asynchronous calls to the query and make use of the lazy loading so I haven't got a 100.000 rows Grid...

Does this exist??? Is it possible??? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still have pagination with Linq, you just have to properly use `Skip` and `Take`. Something like:

```
var bindResults = query.Skip(pageNumber).Take(pageSize);
```

This will execute and only give you the small subset of records you want to display.

Comment: Yeah I know I can, what I was thinking is if in a client side application there isn't a GridView doing this staff automatically by passing it a IQueryable 8-)

Comment: @zapico: You would need to write a custom DataGridView derived class to accomplish this change in behavior. You could achieve some of it with extension methods, but to change how it behaves on scrolling would require much more than that.